# Replacing a trigger with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, ssms

I'm trying to replace a trigger statement with a stored procedure since enabled triggers are not allowed when using the tables in microsoft powerapps.

Simplified, I have to tables:

- KPI_Dim (KPI_ID [PK] , KPIName, KPIGroup...)
- KPICurrent_Fact (KPI_key [FK i.e KPI_Dim[KPI_ID], KPICurrent_ID, KPI_Value...)

Currently, for every new record in KPI_Dim my trigger adds a new row in KPICurrent_Fact with the FK and an autoincremented PK. The rest of the columns e.g. KPI_Value are supposed to be empty.
My simple trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_insert_newKPI] 
ON [dbo].[KPI_Dim]
FOR INSERT AS
INSERT INTO KPICurrent_Fact (KPI_key)
SELECT KPI_ID
FROM INSERTED
```

Now, I want to create a stored procedure that can achieve exactly the same. I have tried to find a solution myself but I'm new to stored procedures and could not find anything that would replicate a trigger.

I'm using SSMS v.18.4.

Thank you for any suggestions.

**EDIT**

Added Table creation and insert into statement code.

```
/* Create KPI_Dim table*/

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KPI_Dim](
    [KPI_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [KPIName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [KPIDescription] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [KPIGroup] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [KPISubGroup] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [KPIOwner] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
    )


  /* Example data */
INSERT INTO [dbo].[KPI_Dim]
    (
    KPIName, 
    KPIDescription,
    KPIGroup,
    KPISubGroup,
    KPIOwner 
    )
VALUES 
    ('TestKPIName','testtest','TestGroup', 'TestSubGroup', 'TestOwner');
```

Comment: having a trigger on a Dimension table that Inserts into a Fact table makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks for the swift reply. 
The purpose is to add a new KPI in the dimension with the associated attributese.g. name, group etc through the power apps interface - creating a new KPI record. Once that KPI is added, it is supposed to be added to the fact table to then add measurements like values and scores again through a power apps interface. It may be that the naming as facts and dimensions are inappropriate but it does not change the overall purpose. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Where is the existing code to insert into `KPI_Dim`

Comment: @Charlieface 
The code to insert values into the KPI_Dim is a manual process initiated through power apps. Replicating this process, it would basically look like a simple insert into statement as below. I also added the creation of the table in case that helps.

Comment: And how about an `OUPUT` clause on that insert statement `OUTPUT inserted.KPI_ID INTO KPICurrent_Fact (KPI_key)`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion and I hope that I understood you correctly. 
Did you mean to add ```OUTPUT inserted.KPI_ID INTO KPICurrent_Fact (KPI_key)``` to the insert statement? It gives an error: The target table 'KPICurrent_Fact' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Also, editing the insert into statement will unfortunately not solve my issue since I will not be able to add the output clause when entering the data through the power apps interface. I need the new KPI_key added after the insert statement is completed.

Comment: Well if you can't edit it then how on earth do you expect to be able to solve this? You can `OUTPUT INTO` a table variable, then `INSERT...SELECT...` from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for OUTPUT Clause and insert into table variable. From the table variable, you can insert into fact table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KPI_Dim](
    [KPI_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [KPIName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [KPIDescription] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [KPIGroup] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [KPISubGroup] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [KPIOwner] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
    )
CREATE TABLE dbo.KPI_Fact
(
 [KPI_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [KPIDIMID] INT NULL FOREIGN KEY references [dbo].[KPI_Dim]([KPI_ID])
)

DECLARE @inserted table(KPI_DIMID INT)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[KPI_Dim]
    (
    KPIName, 
    KPIDescription,
    KPIGroup,
    KPISubGroup,
    KPIOwner 
    )
OUTPUT inserted.KPI_ID INTO @inserted
VALUES 
    ('TestKPIName','testtest','TestGroup', 'TestSubGroup', 'TestOwner');

INSERT INTO dbo.KPI_Fact([KPIDIMID])
SELECT * FROM @inserted
```

| KPI_ID | KPIDIMID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you!! I was able to achieve what I wanted using your input and power automate.

Comment: Is it possible to add another table to the INSERT INTO? Something like INSERT INTO dbo.KPI_Fact([KPIDIMID]) AND dbo.TableXX([KPI_ID])? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PWozcyechowski, you cannot insert into multiple tables that way. you can either use OUTPUT INTO physical table or OUTPUT INTO  table variable and use that table variable to insert into second table

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. Do you have by chance any resource that I could take a look at regarding this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @PWozcyechowski, you can read the MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15